# Why is this batch script not starting up my python program?

Tags: python, batch-file, anaconda

It's a simple script and is supposed to start my python program in the same directory. However, it just runs and closes in a blink.

```
activate base
python CustomGUI.pyw
pause
```

Apparently, it's the `activate base` command which is being an issue. The command window just closes without activating the base environment.

Comment: Use `conda activate base`

Comment: @ComplicatedPhenomenon Not working, same issue.

Answer (score 0):

For running python program using `virtualenv` you don't need to activate it. You can directly use interpreter in the environment.

```
run_gui.bat

C:\path\to\env\scripts\python CustomGUI.pyw
Pause
```

Will work just fine.
For Windows 10 with Anaconda3 and username “jsmith”– the path will be `C:\Users\jsmith\Anaconda3\python`

Comment: Running 
`C:\Users\Neeraj\Anaconda3\python CustomGUI.pyw`
Throws
`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "CustomGUI.pyw", line 2, in <module>
    from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QLabel, QWidget, QPushButton, QSystemTrayIcon, QFileDialog
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.` 
Seems like an environment issue to me.

Comment: If possible use `winpython` as it has transparent execution model. I use it without any hassle.

Comment: That is understood. Don't try to complicate things here.